# Can I scroll horizontally overflowed box?

Tags: html, css

I am stuck with scrolling my overflowed by x box.
I will try explain what I mean in the example below:

[image: Example]

As you can see in the example I have a box, there is horizontal overflow.
Now, for me interesting, does it possible to scroll content of this box on left/right when I am scrolling mouse?

I have tried "over scroll x", but either I did not understand, or it is.

If someone know or have any ideas, feel free to suggest.
I am waiting for your answer!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)? Note: Stack Snippets are preferred over links to external repros for reasons explained in [ask].

Comment: hold down shift key and scroll your mouse wheel for scrolling horizontal.

Comment: That's good idea, but I thought that will be sometimes not obvious for uninformed user, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using Keyboard :

- For vertical scroll you simply do the mouse scroll
- For horizontal scroll you need to hold `shift key` + mouse scroll

#### Programmatically :

⚠ ***This is highly not recommended because the alignment changes and it can't be properly aligned for dynamic contents, but this can be achieved by rotating the container 90 degrees left and right***

```
<div class="overflow-y-scroll h-[600px] w-[180px] -rotate-90 text-4xl">
  <div class="w-[140px] rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="h-[140px] w-[20px] rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="h-[140px] w-[20px] rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="h-[140px] w-[20px] rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="h-[140px] w-[20px] rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="h-[140px] w-[20px] rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="h-[140px] w-[20px] rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="h-[140px] w-[20px] rotate-90">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

---

```
<div class="overflow-y-scroll w-[180px] rotate-90 text-4xl">
  <div class="m-10 w-[140px] -rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="m-10 w-[140px] -rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="m-10 w-[140px] -rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="m-10 w-[140px] -rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="m-10 w-[140px] -rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="m-10 w-[140px] -rotate-90">Hello</div>
  <div class="mt-60 w-[140px] -rotate-90">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

#### [Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/bh93h1uOf3)

Comment: Hi, interesting solution, I will take in on mind, if someone will complain I will provide this feature :)